# How to move data according to the distance

Tags: qgis, distance, tools, boundaries, move

I have a data in the shapefile format. Now I have to move them according to the boundaries. Is their any solution to move according to the distance without manually. I want to select the data with select by location and after points being selected they should be move horizontally or vertically with distance prescribed. I just go for point displacement but every time a shapefile need to export in that process.

[image]

Comment: Sorry: what is the question? Please be more clear. You want to move points? According to a distence: which one? In what direction?

Comment: @babel I just edit the question I think u can understand know

Comment: Have you tried the geoproccessing tool **Affine transform**?

Comment: @BERA I didn't, could you please explain

Comment: i don't see how people can answer this question since it's not clearer even after OP edition ...

Answer (score 3):

There are several options. At least these two solutions should be easy to implement:

1. You can create now, tranlated points using QGIS expressions ([see here how to do it](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)). Use the Geometry by expression option - this creates actual geometries (and a new layer), but might be the better option for a big numer of features. Check the box next to `Selected features only` to translate the selected points only.

   Use the following expression - `5000` is the distance of the translation in x-direction, `9000` in y-direction (change this according to your needs):

   `translate( $geometry, 5000, 9000)`
2. Another option is to select the points and than activate the `Move feature` icon:
   [image].

   If you then move one point, all selected points will be shifted in the same direction and distance. If the icon is not visible, activate the `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar` (`Menu View / Toolbars`). The advantage of this option is that no new layer will be created. However, for a huge number of points, it might not work as well as the other option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't enter anything into the **Displaced** field. It will make a temporary layer instead. No need to create a file.

If you are trying to *replace* the layer, you must save it with the same name as the original. Make sure you have a backup copy to avoid problems.

Or save it to a new file (*point_file_version_2.shp*, for example)

Comment: ofcourse its a good idea but we can do that only for less data. but we cant do that that to huge data it involves efforts

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want. Thanks for the downvote. Good luck.